# What is the power dissipated by a resistor

Tags: resistors

I was doing a homework question, which is states as follows:

> 2 resistors, \$R_1 \$ and \$R_2 \$ are connected in series with a potential difference V across them. The power dissipated by the resistor \$ R_1 \$ is..?

I was basically thinking that it was just \$ \dfrac{V^2}{R_1} \$, but it is wrong. I have no clue why, but I'm guessing it is because I don't understand what is meant by 'power dissipated' by a resistor is. I know that power dissipated by an electric circuit is just \$P=VI \$, but in the case of a single component (in series), how do you calculate this?

p.s. - The answer is either of the following 4:

\$ \dfrac{V^2R_1}{(R_1+R_2)^2} \$

\$ V^2R_1 \times (R_1 + R_2)^2\$

\$ \dfrac{V^2R_2\space^2}{(R_1(R_1 +R_2)^2)}\$

\$ V^2R_2 \space ^2 \times (R_1(R_1 + R_2)^2) \$

Comment: It has. Latex and schematic editor. Please, add schematics and reformat the question. Now is pretty unclear. Ah, the power is always P=U.I

Comment: There are no schematics, so I can't really deliver them, I'm sorry. I'll reformat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what you said I guess that the schematic is this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fD4Vf4.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The resistors are in series, so you need to calculate the power using the correct voltage. The voltage \$V\$ is the voltage across both resistors and in the schematic is called \$Vac\$.

**You need to remember that \$V = Vac = Vab + Vbc\$.**

In order to calculate the power dissipated by R1 you need to use \$Vab\$, that is the voltage across R1.

Comment: Thanks. With this knowledge (assuming I did everything correctly) I have gotten the answer \$ \dfrac{V^2R_1}{(R_1+R_2)^2} \$, which is actually an option.

Comment: Yes, you did it correctly.

Comment: +1 for providing a step towards the answer, but NOT the final answer.

Answer (score 1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fOooeD.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Now, let see:

1. At first, every voltage is always between two points. In the above schematic, there are 3 voltages: \$ U_{12}, U_{23}\$ and \$U_{13} \$
2. Every current is always through some loop. In the above schematic, there is only one current - the same through R1 and R2, because they are serially connected.
3. The power is always \$P=U.I\$ but note - the voltage is across some element and the current is the current through the same element.

So:
$$
P_{R1} = I_{R1}.U_{R1} = I.U_{12}
$$
$$
P_{R2} = I_{R2}.U_{R2} = I.U_{23}
$$
$$
P_{total} = P_{R1} + P_{R2} = I.U_{12} + I.U_{23} = I.(U_{12} + U_{23}) = I.U_{13}
$$

Answer (score 0):

For completeness (and now that solution is known), here's a path to the solution that does not (explicitly) require the voltage across R1 but instead, the series current:

$$p_{R1} = I^2_{series} \cdot R_1 = \dfrac{V^2}{(R_1 + R_2)^2}R_1$$